# One out of two fields required in validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have 2 fields:

> FirstName
>
> LastName

And only one of these is required. But if both are omitted, I want both fields to be highlighted. If one of them is filled in then the model is okay and the form should submit.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8):

All complex validation starts with your view model inheriting from **IValidatableObject**.  You then override **Validate** and put in your own validation rules.

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("A name must be entered.", new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName" });
    }
}
```

Note that this only ensures server side validation for this rule.  If you want it client side, you'll need to write your own JavaScript / jQuery code to deal with the validation.

Comment: with this mark the fields invalid in the same way normal validation attributes do?

Comment: Yes. The `new string[] { "FirstName", "LastName" }` parameter tells the calling code which field(s) failed validation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx), it will help you to do something like this

```
[RequiredIf("PropertyValidationDependsOn", true)]
   public string PropertyToValidate { get; set; }
```

Comment: It can be if you write your own validation attribute, which is relatively simply. Something like the above, or FoolProof Validation http://foolproof.codeplex.com/ or Fluent Validation http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ all cater for this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to do this on client side
this may give you a start

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="name" id="firstName" />
<input type="text" class="name" id="lastName" />
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
```

Button Click Event

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var isValid = false;
    $("input[class='name']").each(function (key, keyValue) {
        //alert(keyValue.value);
        if (keyValue.value.length > 0) {
            isValid = true;
            $(this).css("background", "White");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("background", "RED");
        }
    })
    if (!isValid) {
        // do something 
    }
});
```

To prevent the form submit if not passed validation

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function(e) {
   var isValid = false;
        $("input[class='name']").each(function (key, keyValue) {
            //alert(keyValue.value);
            if (keyValue.value.length > 0) {
                isValid = true;
                $(this).css("background", "White");
            }
            else {
                $(this).css("background", "RED");
            }
        })
        if (!isValid) {
           e.preventDefault() // prevents the form from being submitted
        }    
});
```

test it at http://jsfiddle.net/habo/UpmCv/